# Undo merge in sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have 4 branches

```
1. master
2. develop
3. online_report
4. issue48
```

Developer x is working in `online_report`, he has accidentally merged his work in `develop` and pushed it. I want to undo this merge.

I clicked on the commit I want to go back to before the merge (highlighted in blue), I then selected "`reset current branch to this commit`" and then I choose "`hard`". `develop` is now on this commit but I don't know what to do next?

I want to keep the `develop` branch but I don't want the `online_report` branch into it right now.

[image]

Comment: You had the correct answer by Epp. Any way I'd like to share same work around again that I used to use. (1) Right click on commit you want to revert  
(2) Choose "Reset current branch to this commit"  
(3) Choose Using Mode "Hard - discard all working copy changes"  
(4) Source Tree pull will be displayed.  
(5) ****Don’t pull.  
(6) Force push the commit ( Choose "Terminal" from menu and write command "git push -f")  
(7) The pull will be disappeard and your branch will be revert to that specific commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have fixed this issue locally. You need to push these changes to the remote repository, and then anyone who has already pulled these changes into their local branch must reset their local branch as well.

If you push normally, it will fail because you are pushing something which does not move the remote branch forward. To override this, use the `--force-with-lease` option when pushing `develop`.